importing data to a wallet as not watch-only
I am trying to use private keys, addresses, and public addresses I generated myself. (for educational purpose).
I am working with bitcoin-cli by inserting the inputs I've generated myself. (in CMD)
the following code:
C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli -regtest -named -rpcwallet="legacy" importmulti "[{\"scriptPubKey\":{\"address\":\"<my P2PKH address>\"},\"timestamp\":\"now\",\"pubkeys\":[\"<my compressed public address in hex format>\"],\"keys\":[\"<my private key in WIF format>\"]}]" "{\"rescan\":false}"

returns this output:
[
  {
    "success": true,
    "warnings": [
      "Some private keys are missing, outputs will be considered watchonly. If this is intentional, specify the watchonly flag.",
      "Importing as non-solvable: some required keys are missing. If this is intentional, don't provide any keys, pubkeys, witnessscript, or redeemscript."
    ]
  }
]

but I don't know what keys are missing since I'd generated everything based on the same key
(the order I generated the data:

seed
master key
derived a child key - from now on, I only used the child key
public key based on the child key
P2PKH address based on the public key
copied the values: child key, public key, P2PKH and typed them in the correct place in the template I added above)

Is this because I use only the child key andf not the master key?
How can I prevent importing this data as watch-only?
my main goal is to try to do most of the functions by myself with the least amount of calls necessarily.

all the code for generating the data has already been checked and is working as excepted (can provide python code)
I intend to use the import so I could use this data in regtest mode for transactions

Thank you all in advance!
